# Error CS1729: 'Attachment' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to send mail with attachment through smtp protocol, so I found this tutorial in http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/10/send-email-with-attachment-in-aspnet.html. And tried the following simple coding, the object got created correctly for attachment but it tell me the error that does not take 2 arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class composemail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void SendMail()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(YourEmail.Text);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(YourName.Text);
    mail.Subject = YourSubject.Text;
    mail.Body = Comments.Text;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMail();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Hi. Thanks my error is: error CS1729: 'Attachment' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: That is strange indeed. Btw. You have a `)` too much in the `new Attachment` line and also the property in `MailMessage` is called `Attachments` not `Attachment`.

Comment: Can you shown the real code? There is no method in the code you posted (a class cannot directly contain code).

Comment: Hello my real code.public partial class composemail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void SendMail()
{
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(YourEmail.Text);
mail.From = new MailAddress(YourName.Text);
mail.Subject = YourSubject.Text;
mail.Body = Comments.Text;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
}
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SendMail();
}
}

Comment: @Monish: instead of posting that as a (unreadyble) comment you could have edited/improved your question.

Comment: @M4N: I believe that is his NOW working code. I edited the question with the code in the comment but then I saw his comment on my answer and reverted.

Comment: @M4N Sorry.. I have edited the question. But I think I must first learn what is encapsulating in a method

Comment: @Sani Huttunen If I create a new website and add the same coding, its working but If I create a new form in my working project website and add the coding its not working. Can you tell me what will be the problem is?? Its strange..

Answer (score 1):

As M4N mentioned you cannot have code directly in the class. You need to encapsulate it in a method:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace AttachmentTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var mail = new MailMessage();
      var fs = new FileStream("somepath", FileMode.Open);
      var att = new Attachment(fs, "");
      mail.Attachments.Add(att);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks, ya I tried what you have told and its working. But check the following link, i referred this link for learning they have mentioned like this.. http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/10/send-email-with-attachment-in-aspnet.html

Comment: In that link they do it correctly. The code is incapsulated inside methods.